# How do I make two seperate POST methods for two buttons in the same HTML file?

Tags: html, post, button, methods

So I am trying to place two buttons in the same html file, each of which directing to a different place, like shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>`
</head>
<body>
<div>Impossible! Let me try again!</div>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Try again!">
    <input type="submit" value="No, you failed!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The method supposed to handle the situation in my controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/no", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String triedAgain(Model model) {
        int generatedAgain = numberService.random();
        model.addAttribute("generatedAgain", generatedAgain);
        return "tryagain";
    }
```

If "Try again!" is selected, the below html file should appear:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div th:text="'The number you thought about is: ' + ${generatedAgain} + '. This time for sure!'"/>
</div>
<form method="post">
    <div class="overall">Did I get it right?</div>
    <div class="button">
        <a class="menu-button" href="/yes">Yes!</a>
        <a class="menu-button" href="/no">No!</a>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

BUT, quite obviously, the method from my controller applies to BOTH buttons. The "No, you failed!" one is supposed to direct to a different place, this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>You cheated :-(</div>

<a href="/home">Let me try again!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**So how can I tell the method in my controller which one of the two available buttons it should apply to and to which one it should not?**

I also tried switching to this kind of a button...:

```
<a class="menu-button" href="/failed">No, you failed!</a>
```

... because it has a "href" specified, but if I use it to direct the user to another html... The method that should generate a simple int there, is spitting out a "null".

I am kinda lost here, please help.

Comment: I wonder why you need 2 buttons to submit a form?

Comment: I want every one of them to have a different result. If the user picks "Try again!", then they should be directed to another html where my Java-written code should deploy a method that generates a random number.
If the user picks "No, you failed!", then they should be directed to another html file where there are no Java methods deployed.
Alas, I was told that JQuery is being involved here and I am not really versed in JavaScript, so I guess I just need to study it a bit first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 2 input fields with type=button; assign "id" for each and use action "onclick".

```
<form method="post">
<input id="btn1Submit" type="button" value="Try again!">
<input id="btn2Submit" type="button" value="No, you failed!">
</form>


<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn1Submit").click(function(){
    alert("button1");
});
$("#btn2Submit").click(function(){
    alert("button2");
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but you could give me an example of how and where I should "use the action onclick"?

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot for it. :) Could you also tell me to what should $(document) refer to? Is it my controller? Sorry for being a pest, I am kinda new to it all.

Comment: It  is  jQuery syntax. See jquery.com